# Form from ModelForm kept on showing up 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django

I need help on above error with below django modelform :

**models.py**

```
class Problems(models.Model):
  biodata = models.ForeignKey(Biodata, on_delete = models.CASCADE, default='')
  problem = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  notes = models.CharField(max_length=300)
  status = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  date = models.DateField()

  def __str__(self):
    return self.problem
```

**forms.py:**

```
class Problem_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Problems
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request,id):
   problem = Problems.objects.all().filter(biodata=id)
   problem_form = Problem_Form(instance=problem)

   context = {'problem_form':problem_form}
   return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

**index.html**

```
    <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
        {{ problem_form.as_table }}
    </form>
```

When run the code above, the message 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta' kept on showing up. Please help to resolve this.

Comment: Can you disclose full error

Comment: same error : 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: Get rid of the parentheses after `Meta`